# WebGL 100% Software Mode with RDP and no physical GPU

Tags: webgl, vps, rdp

I want to run multiple Android Apps at the same time on a Virtual Private Server (VPS) under Windows Server 2008 R2, preferably with the chrome app ARChon Custom Runtime 1.2 - x86_64.

Problem is, there is abviously no WebGL with Remote Desktop (RDP) available, even if WebGL is told to have a software mode. No luck with VNC either. I already tried to override and use software emulation by setting the flag in chrome (chrome://flags) - no luck.

I managed to install Bluestacks. All apps are running just fine, so speed is not the problem! Unfortunately Bluestacks is no alternative, because it doesn't support multiple instances.

Any idea on how too force this thing to do it's work?

Comment: This may or may not still work but if you [build chromium from source](http://www.chromium.org/Home) there's a built target for `osmesa` you can also build which you can then use with chromium with `--use-gl=osmesa`. You might even be able to use that osmesa library with regular chrome, just throw the .so/.dll in the correct folder for your os

Comment: Interesting aproach, thank you! I was able to get what I want via a dedicated server and with android sdk manager. Everything runs smooth now.